# check if two rows or columns of a matrix are equal

Tags: java, matrix, compare, multiple-columns

I'm trying to check if two columns of a square matrix are equal. The function is working, but I want to reduce the complexity by using two for instead of three. It's possible? I tried a lot and I couldn't.

```
int a=0;
      boolean equalColumns=false;
        for(int k=0;k<this.getRows()-1;k++){
            for(int i=k;i<this.getRows()-1;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<this.getColumns();j++){
                    if(this.getElement(j, k)==this.getElement(j, i+1)){
                        a++;
                    }
                }
                if(a==this.getColumns()){
                    equalColumns=true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you should show the structure of your class (behind "this") as well as the exact objective you're trying to reach. In the code above, you set equalColumns to true only if the column N you're scanning is equal to the column N-1. However, if the column N+1 is different than N, you will return false whereas N is equal to N-1.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't understand completely your question; if you have a nXn matrix called M and you want to check if col1 and col2 are equals you can do this:

```
for(int row = 0; row<M.lenght;row++)
    if (M[row][col1] != M[row][col2]) return false;
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a method to check on two columns.

- this uses two loops to check each column against the others.
- if any return true, the loop short circuits and displays the result.

```
int n = 8;
boolean result = false;
int[][] mat = new int[n][n];
outer: for (int c1 = 0; c1 < n - 1; c1++) {
    for (int c2 = c1 + 1; c2 < n; c2++) {
        if (result = equalColumns(mat, c1, c2)) {
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
if (result) {
    System.out.println("contains equal columns");
}
```

- this just takes the matrix and the columns to be checked and compares them.
- it also short circuits as soon as a mismatch is found.

```
public static boolean equalColumns(int[][] mat, int cola,
        int colb) {
    for (int row = 0; row < mat.length; row++) {
        if (mat[row][cola] != mat[row][colb]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```